# Cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory [FSL installation on VM]

Tags: linux, virtual-machine

I am having trouble with running FSL on a virtual machine, and was wondering if someone has any idea how to solve the problem -

writing -

```
tbss_1_preproc *.nii.gz
```

Resulted in the creation of two subfolders - "origdata" and "FA", and copied the files to "origdata" but left the "FA" folder empty. The following error message appeared for each of the files:

```
processing 
/usr/local/fsl/bin/fslhd: error while loading shared libraries: libopenblas.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dc: stack empty
/usr/local/fsl/bin/fslhd: error while loading shared libraries: libopenblas.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dc: stack empty
/usr/local/fsl/bin/fslhd: error while loading shared libraries: libopenblas.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dc: stack empty
/usr/local/fsl/bin/fslmaths: error while loading shared libraries: libopenblas.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/local/fsl/bin/fslmaths: error while loading shared libraries: libopenblas.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/local/fsl/bin/fslmaths: error while loading shared libraries: libopenblas.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried following [this link](https://github.com/sermanet/OverFeat/issues/10) and writing

```
sudo yum install libopenblas-base
```

but this resulted in

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.prometeus.net
  * extras: centos.turhost.com
  * updates: mirror.muvhost.com
    No package libopenlabs-base available.
    Error: Nothing to do
```

Does anyone have some experience with such error messages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered exactly the same issue. It seems as if for the VMware setup, the relevant package is not called lipopenblas-*base* but lipopenblas-*serial*, see also here: 
https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/openblas-serial-0.3.3-2.el7.x86_64.rpm.html

This solved it for me:

`sudo yum install libopenblas-serial`

Answer (score 0):

its old question but it might help someone run following commands and follow instructions.

sudo wget https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/o/openblas-serial-0.3.3-2.el7.x86_64.rpm

sudo yum localinstall openblas-serial-0.3.3-2.el7.x86_64.rpm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).